# SQL: How to update column values from a specific Select with a Windowed Function (stuff, dense rank, over)

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what I would like to do:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET ColumnA = SELECT stuff(ColumnA, 1, 2, 11+dense_rank() over(order by left(ColumnA, 10))) from TableA
WHERE Year = '2021'
AND Type = 'LA'
```

I would like to set a column's values to the values of that SELECT

Comment: `Year = '2021'` makes me want to cry. If it's an `int` column why compare it to a string, if it's a `varchar` why isn't it an `int`

Answer (score 2):

You could use an updatable CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, STUFF(ColumnA, 1, 2, 11 +
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LEFT(ColumnA, 10))) AS new_val
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Year = '2021' AND Type = 'LA'
)

UPDATE cte
SET ColumnA = new_val;
```